# Import new data only from a google sheet to another via google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import only new row and unique rows from a sheet to another.

The flow should be the following:
1. Data are pushed to a google sheet every time a form is submitted
2. Data of this first sheet are printed in a second sheet only if they are new entries hence, not existing already in the second sheet.

I've created a script already that creates a new array via .map() method, filtering the columns that I want to import and print from the first to the second sheet. The problem is that I don't want to print the whole array every time since is slow and inefficient. I want to print just the new entries in the second sheet. My idea was to concatenate the content of the two sheets, create a third from these two containing only the unique values (thus only the new ones) and then print in the last empty row. I've tried but I didn't make it, I'm not even sure it's the most efficient way to do it.

Any **ideas** on how to do it in an **efficient way**?

```
function importData() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('_RawDataTable');
var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
var rawData = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

// get only the columns I need
var dataInvoices = rawData.map(function(r) {
return [r[0], r[1], r[11], r[2], r[3], r[5]]
});

// print the data in the first empty row
outputSheet.getRange(outputSheet.getLastRow(),1, dataInvoices.length, dataInvoices[0].length).setValues(dataInvoices);

}
```

### Edit

Here you have the sheets (all data are fake): 
[Origin Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2PmB.png)
[Output Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWsvf.png)

In this example the origin sheet has a few more entries than the output sheeet. The goal would be to **only** print the new rows in the output sheet without have to replance everything as from the code above. *(obviously in the real sheet the rows are thousands so it's very inefficient to replace all the data set every time, hence the need of adding only the new ones)*

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail situation of your spreadsheet, how about using the difference of the number of rows of both 2 sheets after the values were copied? When new entries are put to a sheet, can the difference of rows be used as the new entries? If I misunderstand your situation, in order to understand correctly your situation, can you provide the sample spreadsheet including the input and output you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tanaike, I'm not sure I understand what you mean though :) I've edited the post adding the images as you suggested to clarify the goal, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your sample, you want to add the row 9-10 of Origin Sheet to the last row of Output Sheet. Is my understanding correct?